# how to modifiy the case in java with too many "if else"

Tags: java

Here is my coding part of project. Although I have completed the task, it is too long and looks messy. Is there anyway that can modifiy the structure and make it shorter? Thanks alot.

Summarize of the code: It is about checking the record exists or not in the database. If you need some details, please let me know

```
        CheckCertRecordDao checkCertHistRecordDao = new CheckCertRecordDaoImpl(connection);
        //CheckCertHistRecord
        int countCertRecord = 0;
        countCertRecord = checkCertHistRecordDao.countCertHistRecordBySerialNo(certIdList);
        if (countCertRecord == 0) {
            InsertCertRecordDao insertCertHistRecordDao = new InsertCertRecordDaoImpl(connection);
            insertedCertHist = insertCertHistRecordDao.insertCertHistRecord(certIdList);
            if (insertedCertHist = true) {
                countCertRecord = checkCertHistRecordDao.countCertHistRecordBySerialNo(certIdList);
                if (countCertRecord == certIdList.size()) {
                    Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Number of inserted cert hist record is matched with the certIdList!");
                    String ModeRecord = null;
                    CheckModeRecordDao checkModeHistRecordDao = new CheckModeRecordDaoImpl(connection);
                    ModeRecord = checkModeHistRecordDao.checkModeHistRecordByHcp(modeId);
                    if (ValidValue.isEmpty(ModeRecord)) {
                        InsertModeRecordDao insertModeHistRecordDao = new InsertModeRecordDaoImpl(connection);
                        insertedModeHist = insertModeHistRecordDao.insertModeHistRecord(modeId);
                        if (insertedModeHist = true) {
                            ModeRecord = checkModeHistRecordDao.checkModeHistRecordByHcp(modeId); 
                            if (!ValidValue.isEmpty(ModeRecord)) {
                                Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserted mode hist record is completed!");
                                int countclientRecord = 0;
                                CheckConnClientRecordDao checkConnClientHistRecordDao = new CheckConnClientRecordDaoImpl(connection);
                                countclientRecord = checkConnClientHistRecordDao.checkConnClientHistRecord(clientIdList);
                                if (countclientRecord == 0 ) {
                                    InsertConnClientRecordDao insertConnClientHistRecordDao = new InsertConnClientRecordDaoImpl(connection);
                                    insertedConnClientHist = insertConnClientHistRecordDao.insertConnClientHistRecord(clientIdList); 
                                    Als.audit(AlsAction.INFO, "insertedConnClientHist = " + insertedConnClientHist);
                                    if (insertedConnClientHist = true) {
                                        countclientRecord = checkConnClientHistRecordDao.checkConnClientHistRecord(clientIdList);
                                        Als.audit(AlsAction.INFO, "countclientRecord = " + countclientRecord);
                                        Als.audit(AlsAction.INFO, "clientIdList = " + clientIdList.size());
                                        if (countclientRecord == clientIdList.size()) {                                         
                                            Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Number of inserted client hist record is matched with the clientIdList");   
                                            CheckConnInfoDao checkConnInfoHistRecordDao = new CheckConnInfoDaoImpl(connection);
                                            int connInfoCount = checkConnInfoHistRecordDao.countConnInfoHistRecord(InfoIdList);
                                            if (connInfoCount == 0 ) {
                                                InsertConnInfoRecordDao insertConnInfoHistRecordDao = new InsertConnInfoRecordDaoImpl(connection);
                                                insertedConnInfoHist = insertConnInfoHistRecordDao.insertConnInfoHistRecord(InfoIdList);
                                                if (insertedConnInfoHist =  true) {
                                                    Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserting ConnInfo Hist Record is completed!"); 
                                                    connInfoCount = checkConnInfoHistRecordDao.countConnInfoHistRecord(InfoIdList);
                                                    if (connInfoCount == InfoIdList.size() ){
                                                        Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Number of inserted connInfo hist record is matched with the InfoIdList");
                                                    } else {
                                                        response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                        response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                        Als.audit(AlsAction.INFO, "Number of inserted connInfo hist record is [NOT] matched with the InfoIdList");
                                                    }   
                                                } else {
                                                    response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                    response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                    Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserting ConnInfo Hist Record with error!");   
                                                }                                                       
                                            } else {
                                                response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                                Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "connInfoCount =/= 0, existing the connInfo hist record already!");  
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                            response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                            Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Number of inserted client hist record is [NOT] matched with the clientIdList");                                                                             
                                        }
                                    } else {                                        
                                        response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                        response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                        Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserting ConnClient Hist Record with error!"); 
                                    }   
                                } else {
                                    response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                    response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                    Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "countclientRecord =/= 0, existing the connClient hist record already!");    
                                }
                            } else {
                                response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                                Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserted mode hist record with error!");
                            }   
                        } else {
                            response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                            response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                            Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserted mode hist record with error!!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                        response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                        Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "ModeRecord is not empty, existing the mode hist record already!");
                    }   
                } else {
                    response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                    response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                    Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Number of inserted cert hist record is [NOT] matched with the certIdList");
                }
            } else {
                response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
                Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserted cert hist record with error!!");
            }
        } else {
            response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
            response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
            Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "countCertRecord =/= 0, existing the cert hist record already!");
```

Comment: First one: this `if (insertedConnClientHist == true)`  you can change to this: `if (insertedConnClientHist)`

Comment: **1)** `if (insertedCertHist = true)` will assign `true` to the variable, and always execute the subsequent statement/block; you probably wanted `if (insertedCertHist == true)` which leads to **2)** totally unnecessary to compare to `true`, that is, use `if (insertedCertHist)` (@tostao)

Comment: Will you describe in words what this code is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me describe my coding in detail.

Firstly, checking the data record is exist or not in database

If yes then return error, If no ,then process the "insterting record to database -A" action.

Secondly, check the insterting the record to database A is success or not. 

If no then return error, If yes, then process inserting the record to database B. 

All of the code is doing the similar logic.

Comment: You can create a method for repetitive codes, like setting response object values. You can even pass the values as parameters if some values are going to be different for different if blocks.

Comment: You can extract some parts of the code to another method, so the code doesn't look too complex and is also easily understandable. IDEs will help with that.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably more todo, but you can begin with :

1. Stop code repetition : create a new function instead of repeating these line :

```
response.setStatusCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
response.setResultMsgByCode(SirResponse.ERROR_UNKNOWN_CD);
Als.audit(AlsAction.EXCEPTION, "Inserted mode hist record with error!!");
```

2. Avoid nesting if statements

```
if (!condition) {
 return 
}
```